# Suggestions for placing both App and Company logos in a Dashboard Design

Tags: dashboard, logos, organizations, product

[image]

I am designing a dashboard page for employee performance application . The dashboard page have the space for product logo, employee settings, employee profile pic, name and designation, menu bar.

We are planning to sell this app to the other organization as well. So we have to include their organisation logo to the dashboard. So, can you guys suggest me some of the best suitable location to place this organisational logo.

Comment: Hi Fazil, welcome to UX.SE. The StackExchange environment is not well suited for general discussions and suggestions. While we can certainly *suggest* placement, one answer would be no more correct than another without a great deal more context. Your users, their behavior, and the work flows are what ultimately answer the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Top-left, combined with your own branding.

[image]

While Brian is correct that companies want to have their own branding, putting *only* their branding there is bad for troubleshooting and supporting the end-user.

Though in some cases (apps distributed to the public) company branding gets prioritized over usability, this does not apply to back-end and B2B software. The end users are employees so there should not be any brand-loyalty problems. For example; when you sell a make-your-burger app to McD, Wendy's and BK, those companies could lose customers when they find out about the competition's apps. But when you sell an ingredient-inventory-app to those companies, you're not expecting employees to jump ship and try to work for the competition.

Even if you supply your customer with a (branded) set of documentation, the internet will still know more. When I google "[view cpanel error logs](http://www.google.com/search?q=view%20cpanel%20errors%20log)", the first result... is not from the official site, but from a hosting provider. And that's a pretty common action.

However, your branding should be subtle, and the customer logo should be more prominent. You are working for them, your program is working for them, so the branding should indicate that relationship.

Answer (score 2):

From experience large companies will not want any other branding than there own. They spend alot of time training and conditioning employees to follow company values and identity. So if you are trying to sell "ABC PRODUCT" to "COMPANY LTD" they will almost certainly require the removal of the "ABC PRODUCT" logo. I would therefore recommend the header will look like this:

COMPANY LTD_____________DASHBOARD TITLE_____________SETTINGS

Solving the space issue. I would reccomend creating a post sale visual with the target company logo top left top have any chance of a successful sale.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Top left is the standard position (see this site for example!).

One other thing to consider if you're reselling is that not all logos fit within a square shape very easily - they may have vertical height, or be a particularly long name which will need to be resized to fit.

Answer (score -1):

### My Suggestion is

1. Product Logo is in right place.
2. At a place of setting I would suggest you place Hamburger.On hover on      Hamburger we will show employee **Avatar Pic** , next comes setting , details & my account/Logout.
3. In Left side On that we will show Organization pic and name which will be sensible.

Note *

- **Hamburger** - I am adding pic if you are not aware of that word.
- **Avatar pic** - It is employee pic.

[image]

**If I design I would follow this because end of the day origination gives us money , not employee.So let highlight them as bright as possible.**

Comment: Hamburger menu should only be used in cases where there is very little space, or you want to look very minimalist (for example, photo gallery overlay).  This dashboard has plenty of space, and it will be busy with statistics, text, and more. So, no hamburger menu.

Comment: Hamburger it doesn't have rules to define where to use.It just a icon to show additional information on click.We can use hamburger I am sure about we cant decline it.

Comment: Every thing in design needs a good reason. You do not give a good reason for  hamburger menu here. But there are reasons to not use hamburger: takes more clicks, not everyone recognizes it, you cannot see the options. No reasons for using + yes reasons for avoiding = do not use.

Comment: There is good / bad reason.Every one has there own view on design process / Imagination.Hamburger it self is show additional information on click.It wont take more clicks , when it come to recognizance it wasnt rocket science that user wont recognize the hamburger icon.End of the day it was just icon. Reasons for using + NO reasons for avoiding = Good to use .

Comment: Hamburger showing more icons on click = all those icons take one more click. You're still not giving a reason why to use the hamburger menu here.